# How do you use Papa Parse without jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, papaparse

I am trying to implement Papa Parse, but I do not want to use the jquery library. Could someone please show me how to parse in normal javascript using a file form my local storage?

Ok, so when I do this I am getting the string value and not the csv values. What am I doing wrong? Also, where do I insert the callback function that I want to use?

```
function parseMe(url) {
    Papa.parse(url, {
        complete: function(results) {
            console.log(results); // results appear in dev console
        }
    });
}

parseMe('csv/test.csv');
```

Comment: PapaParse doesn't require jQuery and the documentation is pretty clear. What, specifically, is your problem?

Comment: I want to make a javascript object for each of the rows in my csv. I want the first row to be question and the second to be name. How would I do this so that I can access any of the rows when I need them. Could you please provide the code?

Comment: @MattButler You can't ask people to write code for you here, sorry. Try it, then if you still have problems, edit your question to include what you've tried. To parse a file is easy. Take a look at the documentation; the source of the demo page may also be of interest to you for a working example.

Comment: Please see the revised post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close, but `file` is not a string, it's a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object obtained from the DOM ([docs](http://papaparse.com/docs#local-files)). To do this, you will need to place a `<input type="file">` tag in your page. The user will have to select the file. After they've chosen a file, you can obtain the File object with something like `document.getElementById("file").files[0]` -- assuming you've given the input tag an ID of "file" of course.

Also, you can cut out all the cruft in the config object since those are all defaults.

```
function parseMe(file) {
    Papa.parse(file, {
        complete: function(results) {
            console.log(results); // results appear in dev console
        }
    });
}

parseMe(document.getElementById("file").files[0]);
```

Parsing a file is asynchronous so you have to get the results in a callback function which executes later.

Comment: I suspect you are new to JavaScript. I recommend reading about some basic things like how to interact with the DOM (MDN has some good tutorials) and what asynchronous code is / why callbacks are necessary. I think that will be of more help than I will be at this point.